# implement inequality symbols for a custom class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading

I have this class:

```
    

class Dog<T: Comparable<T>>(private val name: T, private val weight: T): Comparable<Dog<T>> {
 override fun compareTo(other: Dog<T>): Int {
  TODO("Not yet implemented")
 }
 
 override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
  return (other is Dog<*>) && (other.weight == weight)
 }
}
```

and I want to compare any two dogs based on their `weight`s, not names like this:

```
    fun main() {
     val dog1 = Dog("Dog1", 10)
     val dog2 = Dog("Dog2", 11)
    
     println(dog1 > dog2)
     println(dog1 <= dog2)

}
```

I am at a loss to implement the `compareTo` function. I would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Do you really need ```T```? Can you have something like this ```class Dog(private val name: String, private val weight: Int): Comparable<Dog>```?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. No, it should be a string. But I still need the T in weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `weight` needs to be generic, you can try with this `Dog` class:

```kotlin
class Dog<T : Comparable<T>>(private val name: String, private val weight: T): Comparable<Dog<T>> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Dog<T>): Int {
        return weight.compareTo(other.weight)
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other == null || other !is Dog<*>) return false
        return name == other.name && weight == other.weight
    }
}
```

Just make sure your `weight` has `compareTo()` function properly implemented.

Comment: Thank you so much. I now can even make `name` generic, too. How sweet. Much obliged.